# django one request.is_ajax() check and multiple forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

so i have this code that checks if there is an ajax request and then handle the form stuff if there is, but my problem is it's kind of repetitive to check each time like you will see in the code that i will add, what i want is to check only once and then say if form_1 do some stuff, if form_2 do some stuff
here is the code:

```
   if request.is_ajax():
       Form1 = form_1(request.POST)
       if form_1.is_valid():
          # do some stuff
       else:  
         # do some stuff)

   if request.is_ajax():
       Form2 = form_2(request.POST)
       if form_2.is_valid():
          # do some stuff
       else:  
         # do some stuff
```

what i want to do is something like this or an alternative to the following:

```
   if request.is_ajax():
      if it's form1:
         # do form1 stuff
      elif it's form2:
         # do form2 stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the form as a parameter of the request, something like:

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.GET.get('form1'):
    ...

elif request.is_ajax() and request.GET.get('form2'):
    ...

else:
    ...
```

Comment: why did you use GET instead of POST

Comment: Can be either, its the same code - just replace GET with POST.